# Select2 - search function keyword

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

my first time to use stackoverflow and i just want to ask question.

im using select2 for my search function and i want something like this

```
<select class="select form-control" name="state" onchange="searchMenu(this)">
  <option value="" selected hidden></option>
     @for (int i = 0; i < Menu2.Count; i++)
       {
        <option class="form-control" value="some-url" title="some-tooltip">(name) (hidden name)</option>
       }
</select>
```

I want to have a part on my option name to be hidden but still can be searchable (works like a keyword). Thank you